# How to block unregistered users to create data in a class of Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I have tried to figure out how to set a rule in Parse.com so that only registered users can create a database in a particular class. I'm not talking about editing, but to create. I tried this with Pointer <_User> and deactivated the function created to Public, but even so it was not possible.

[Image to the CLPs edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEhjg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to negate that Parse.User.current() check:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Perfil", function(request, response) {
    if (!Parse.User.current()) {
        response.error("Just registered users");
    } else {
        response.success();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Parse.Cloud.beforeSave` handler in cloud code which can verify the logged in user permissions before allowing the save.